# Where can you use ARM template functions in policy definitions?

Tags: azure-policy

I'm trying to use ARM template functions in `effect` part of policy but it does not seem to allow to do something which ARM template supports `utcnow('YYYY')`. Per article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-functions) I shall be able to use this function at least in parameters and then pass it but it being passed as string. Policy example is below. I'm trying to convert default utcnow() to short date string and failing to do so via policy

```
"policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "field": "tags['datemodified']",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags['datemodified']",
          "exists": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4a9ae827-6dc8-4573-8ac7-8239d42aa03f"
        ],
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "tags['datemodified']",
            "value": "[parameters('timeOfExecution')]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "timeOfExecution": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "timeOfExecution",
        "description": null
      },
      "defaultValue": "[utcnow('yyyy-MM-dd')]"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Microsoft support following ARM template functions are not supported inside Azure policy:

```
dateTimeAdd
utcNow(format)
deployment
environment
variables
extensionResourceId
listAccountSas
listKeys
listSecrets
list*
pickZones
providers (deprecated)
reference
resourceId
subscriptionResourceId
tenantResourceId
managementGroup
tenant
newGuid
```